# Test methods in the same class as main with JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

OK, so before we start let me state that I have been googling and searching for an answer to my question for quite a while now and haven't been able to find a suitable one (the keywords are tricky since I keep getting unrelated posts and sites as results).

Now, moving on I have a Java class that contains a my main method and a number of other functions. I want to test these functions using JUnit but I can't instantiate a class that has main in it, if I simply try to call the function I get an error saying the function is outside the namespace even though both files are in the same package, and I get an error trying to import the file.

Is there anyway to test these functions using JUnit?

P.S. Yes I know that you can put them in a new class, but I don't think it is overkill to create a new class just for testing or to put in 2 functions that are for parsing user input, and there is still the issue of testing the main function itself (and it is not uncommon to write a main method just for testing).

---

So this is what happened. Since I don't use Java very often I ended up creating private data members in the class but treated them as I would globals in a C++ program. In consequence I initialized them in main and didn't think of making a constructor and hence the problem with instantiating the class. When that didn't work I tried the . form but since the methods referenced the private data members I would get an error without instantiating the class. Thanks to the guys that noticed the constructor thing.

Comment: Why can't you instantiate a class that has a main method in it?

Comment: I want to test these functions using JUnit but I can't instantiate a class that has main in it -- huh?

Comment: "can't instansiate a class that has main in it". Sure you can. I don't understand what your problem is. Can you elaborate or provide a bit of code?

Comment: A class that has a main method is no different from other classes. You shouldn't have problems instantiating it.

Comment: problem with the constructor :P

Comment: Ok so I'm including an explanation of what ended up happening in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You absolutely *can* create an instance of a class which contains a `main` method, so long as it has an accessible constructor of course.

Likewise you absolutely *can* call a static method directly, using `MyClassName.myMethodName`.

Having a `main` method in a class makes absolutely *no* difference to it in terms of the Java language itself - so you can test it just as you would any other class.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I just wrote `SomeClass` with `main` inside and it's perfectly testable by `SomeClassTest` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, did you declare constructors as private in the class with main method? It will help a lot if you can post some code snippet and exact error message you're getting.